# Why does my Python script not receive the data the process sends on stdin?

Tags: python, stdout, stdin

I am using asyncio to launch 2 simple tasks:

- one that sends data to the stdin of another Python script.
- one that reads data from the stdout of this Python script.

However, it looks like the data is not received by the Python script.

Here is the script, named `stdin_listener.py` that simply writes back to stdout what it receives on stdin:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    sys.stdout.write("LINE: {}\n".format(line))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Here is the script that that uses asyncio to play with the stdin and stdout of the process:

```
import asyncio
import sys

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.ProactorEventLoop())

args = ["C:/Python27/python.exe", "D:/Dev/LoadTests/stdin_listener.py"]
kwargs = {}


async def start_process():
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        *args,
        stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        **kwargs
    )
    process.stdin.write("Hello process!\n".encode('utf-8'))
    return process


async def read_from_process(process):
    while True:
        read_stdout = asyncio.ensure_future(process.stdout.readline())
        line = (await read_stdout).rstrip().decode()
        print("RECEIVED:", line)
        if not line:
            break


async def write_to_process(process):
    done = asyncio.ensure_future(process.wait())
    while not done.done():
        process.stdin.write("Hello process!\n".encode('utf-8'))
        await asyncio.wait_for(done, timeout=1.0)


async def run_test():
    process = await start_process()
    tasks = []
    tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(read_from_process(process)))
    tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(write_to_process(process)))
    await asyncio.wait(tasks)
    print('Exit code:', process.returncode)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(run_test())
```

What happens is that the Python script receives nothing on stdin and the `read_from_process` coroutine keeps awaiting for stdout forever.

When I run the Python script alone and I write on stdin in a shell, I have my lines sent to stdout as expected.

Note: I am running this on Windows.

Do you know what the problem is?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do the `asyncio.subprocess.PIPE` file types handle universal newlines, or do you need to change your `\n` characters to `os.linesep` ?

Comment: I have changed \n to \r\n (os.linesep) in the script that reads on stdin and in the script and writes to stdin, but it did not change anything.

Comment: Second question: do you need to flush `process.stdin` in the `write_to_process()` method and `sys.stdout` in the `read_from_process()` method?